# What does the following code (pandas.DataFrame.groupby()) do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was reading this blog about predicting the survivability of the titanic dataset. While cleaning the data, the blogger used the following code to fill empty `Age` values:

```
#Age was the most intricate column to be filled. Age had 263 missing values. I initially categorized 
#the people on the basis of their salutations. A basic Python’s string split was enough to extract 
#the title from each name. There were 18 different titles.

td['Salutation'] = td.Name.apply(lambda name: name.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip())

#I then grouped the titles with Sex and PClass.

grp = td.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])

#The median of the group was then substituted in the missing rows.

grp.Age.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
td.Age.fillna(td.Age.median, inplace = True)
```

`td` is the training dataset.

Why did the blogger use this:

```
grp.Age.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
td.Age.fillna(td.Age.median, inplace = True)
```

What is the `grp` thing doing.

[This is the link to the blog.](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-kaggle-s-titanic-problem-3193cb56f6ca)

Thanks for your help this is really bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> A groupby operation involves some combination of splitting the object, applying a function, and combining the results. This can be used to group large amounts of data and compute operations on these groups.

As you can see in the examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',

                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],

                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

df
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0

df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()
```

Output:

```
        Max Speed
Animal
Falcon      375.0
Parrot       25.0
```

This function groups all equivalent values in one column, and modifies the other columns. In the above example, the code groups the 4 rows into 2 rows, by finding the same values in the `Animal` column, and applies a `mean` to the `Max Speed` column.

Comment: I mean why is group by used in the blog when at the end td.Age.fillna(td.Age.median, inplace = True) this is used

Comment: @Prabodh That code removes the `NaN`s and replaces them with the median value of the `Age` column.

Comment: But why two times? grp.Age.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())) and
td.Age.fillna(td.Age.median, inplace = True)